# In Acts 4:13 how did Peter and John's ignorance indicate that they had been with Jesus?

Tags: acts

> KJV Act_4:13  Now when they saw the boldness of Peter and John, and
>   perceived that they were unlearned and ignorant men, they marveled;
>   and they took knowledge of them, that they had been with Jesus.

This sounds like stereotyping, where one might see a person wearing a MAGA hat with camo that slides half way up their belly guzzling a sixpack and assume that they are a fundamentalist Christian. Did Christians have such a bad reputation that quickly?!

Or was it only their boldness that Luke is saying they associated with Jesus?

[image: Obviously a Christian?]

Comment: Stating a fact it is not stereotyping. The Apostles were ignorant and uneducated by the standards of the rules, elders, and scribes. It may not be tactful, but it is accurate. I think your question is reasonable but understand why someone would downvote - injecting current politics is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the High Priest Annas and Caiaphas, acting as the spokesperson for the rulers and elders and scribes assembled asked a simple question:

> And when they had set them in the midst, they inquired, “By what power or by what name did you do this?” (Acts 4:7) [ESV]

The direct answer to this question is, "By the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth."

> ...In the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth, rise up and walk!” (Acts 3:6)

The answer Peter gives is not a straight forward response:

> Then Peter, filled with the Holy Spirit, said to them, “Rulers of the people and elders, if we are being examined today concerning a good deed done to a crippled man, by what means this man has been healed, let it be known to all of you and to all the people of Israel that by the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth...
>
> whom you crucified, whom God raised from the dead—by him this man is standing before you well. This Jesus is the stone that was rejected by you, the builders, which has become the cornerstone. And there is salvation in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given among men by which we must be saved.” (Acts 4:8-12)

After answering the question by saying the man was healed by the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth, Peter continued by using Psalm 118:22 and Joel 2:32 to accuse them of crucifying Jesus and by saying the name not only healed the cripple but will bring salvation:

> The stone that the builders rejected
>       has become the cornerstone. (Psalm 118:24)
>
> And it shall come to pass that everyone who calls on the name of the Lord shall be saved... (Joel 2:32)

Peter's use of Psalm 118 is as a midrash to implicate those assembled, or perhaps only Annas and Caiaphas for crucifying Jesus and to introduce a new topic, salvation:

> Peter's use of Psalm 118:24
>   "the builders rejected" - Annas and Caiaphas/the rulers, elders, scribes
>   "the cornerstone" - Jesus Christ of Nazareth, the only name given by which we are saved

In essence Peter is saying "The crippled man was healed by the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth. But why are you asking me about how a crippled man can walk? You should be asking me about how those who crucified an innocent man can be saved."

An uneducated man would not be expected to defend himself by using Scripture to accuse those questioning him of a more serious crime. Moreover, implied in Peter's response is the ability for those guilty of crucifying Jesus to obtain salvation.

Comment: I like it! Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a general ignorance, such as we might use the word, but referred to the Sanhedrin's surprise at their boldness, and their ability to reason from Scripture and apply it to Christ. John Stott on this passage:

> The court was astonished by the courage of Peter and John,
>   particularly because they were unschooled (*agrammatoi*, meaning not
>   that they were illiterate, but that they had received no proper
>   training in Rabbinic theology) and ordinary men (*idiōtai*, meaning
>   ‘laymen’ or ‘non-professionals’). But then they took note that these
>   men had been with Jesus, who also lacked both a formal theological
>   education﻿ and professional status as a Rabbi. Nevertheless, they
>   could also see before their eyes the incontrovertible evidence of the
>   healed cripple. (From: *The Message Of Acts*.)

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks for the response. There is some good stuff in there. I'm not sure I see how the healing figures into the verse though. Ignoring that sentence, Stott seems to be saying that their taking note of their being with Jesus "tipped the scale" because he says "but then they took note that they had been with Jesus". Am I correct that he's framing it, "They saw they were ignorant but they also took note that they had been with Jesus". Am I hearing his view right? If not it doesn't seem to flow.

Comment: I think you're right. They had the same boldness (and results!) as Jesus, despite sharing His "unschooled" status.

Comment: I've always read it that what they observed led them to associate that they were Jesus' disciples.